# Get axios response data in a global const outside Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, constants, reactive

I get a nice responce from axios call from my REST api in mounted() webhook and I know how to do it correctly:

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#flashcard-app',
    data: {
        card : cards[index],
        cards: cards,
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            this.cards = response.data
        });
    },
```

When I try to simply output my cards collection like this: **{{cards}}** it showes up just fine, in a nice JSON correct way.

### BUT

When I try to show this collection in some specific way like below, it crashes in console and  says that it's undefiend

```
<li v-on:click="toggleCard(card)" id="list">
        <transition name="flip">
            <p class="card" v-if="!card.flipped" key="question">
                {{card.question}}
            </p>
            <p class="card" v-else key="answer">
                {{card.answer}}
            </p>
        </transition>
    </li>
</ul>


<div  v-if="card.flipped">
    <button class="button-card btn btn-success" id="remember" v-on:click="next()">Remember</button>
    <button class="button-card btn btn-danger" id="don't" v-on:click="next()">Don't Remember</button>
    <button class="button-card btn btn-warning" id="!sure" v-on:click="next()">Not Sure</button>
</div>
```

The thing is, when I try to do the same thing with hardcoded const collection it works just fine!

I think it is connected with lifecycle somehow, but I ve tried beforeCreate() and created() already and it doesnt seem to work at all(

**Can I get my axios response to a const, outside of vue component somehow?**

Comment: Is `card` defined? Where do you get your `index` from?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, index is an outside variable defined like this: let index = 0; in the same file.
I'm not sure about my defenition being correct, could you offer me some variants?

Comment: It should work like this, but best practice would be to have an index variable within the data part of the Vue component. The currently selected item could then be derived from `cards` and `index` with a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). But the reason, the code propably does not work is the order of which it is executed: You are setting `cards` in the callback after loading the cards remotely. The value of `card` however is set during initialization of the component. You need to refactor this (with computed properties). You also access cards without `this` in data

Comment: Could you please give me an example of refactored code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cards is not defined" error you are receiving does not come from your HTML but rather from this snippet:

```
data: {
    card : cards[index],
    cards: cards,
}
```

What is cards at this point? Unless you have a global variable outside the Vue instance named `cards`, both assignments will fail.

The best practice would be to begin with initializing `cards` to an empty list and `card` to null:

```
data: {
    card : null,
    cards: [],
}
```

Then you can implement the `created()` hook, make the request and populate the cards list.

If you always want to set `card` to, say, the first card in the list you can watch for changes in the `cards` variable using a computed property.

```
created() {
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.cards = response.data
    });
}
```

Comment: vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'flipped' of undefined" 
Still thinks that cards is not defined

Comment: @dimlucas You probably mean `created()` or `mounted()`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: I tried your method and now it didn't totally crash, but loaded up the info, well I could say that it helped, but there is still one more thing I want to ask
What if I want to add a boolean field with same name to all objects in this cards collection? I tried 
this.cards.forEach(function (e) {
            e.flipped = false;
        }) in created() when I get my axios done, but it didnt work

Comment: Try this inside `created()`:
`this.cards = response.data.map(d => { d.flipped = false; return d })`

Answer (score 0):

My code works take a look a it. What I did is install parcel which is a bundler that bundles all your javascript files into one file maybe that could, that way you can import your packages.

```
// HTML 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="app">
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
      <section id="posts">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="post in posts">
            {{ post.title }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </section>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
// js

import axios from 'axios';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'hello world',
    posts: [],
  },
  created() {
    this.message = 'post app';
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    axios.get(url).then(data => {
      this.posts = data.data;
    });
  },
});
```

Parcel

https://parceljs.org/

You need a package.json , install it with npm init --y

It is a different approach, but it could work.

Comment: I've tried your code, it doesnt seem to make any difference, unfortunately(
Still writes that 'cards' is not defined
Looks like it's not defined when the html is being compiled, although created() hook is before it, according to your documentation link(
Any ideas why it works with a hardcoded const variable but not with axios response?

Comment: Could you post your code in an online editor? that would help a lot ;) thank you! That way I can see where the console log is happening.

Comment: I'm afraid I can recreate everything excpet the axios get request, as it comes from my spring app that is being started locally, so I don't really know the other way to recreate axios request. The code works with hardcoded values unfortunately(

Comment: I edited my code, with some example that you could reference, let me know if it makes sense!